# Understanding ask - group Indexes together in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, grouping

To be short - the code works.

But how ?

I made a PHP curl so scrape a website and get some events. Works.

Then i wanted to group some scraped events together. Tested some variations and to the end i did this:

`$communities[$current_color][] = $li->plaintext;`

Works. But i cant imagine how this is a grouping function....

Anyone an idea?

Here is the most important of my code:

```
echo '<article class="month">';
foreach( $html->find('tr') as $tr ){

    $montName = $tr->find('.ev_td_left', 0);
    echo '<h3>' . $montName->plaintext . '</h3>';
    echo '<ul>';

        foreach( $tr->find('li') as $li ){

            $style = $li->style;
            preg_match( "/#.{6}/", $style, $li_bgcolor );

            /**
             * Array nach Farben gruppieren
             */
            $current_color = $li_bgcolor[0];
            $communities[$current_color][] = $li->plaintext;

            echo '<li><span class="event" style="background-color:'.$li_bgcolor[0].';"></span>'.$li->plaintext.'</li>';

        }

    echo '</ul>';
    echo '<br/>';

}
echo '</article>';
```

Comment: You're creating a multidimensional array, where the color (`$current_color`) is the grouping key and you append to that array the value of `$li->plaintext` using the square bracket syntax `[] = `

Comment: Thanks for that, yes, but i wonder that the foreach loop goes from the front to the back of the available elements (events in this case) to display them. How is ist possible that the result is grouped without looping through the events multiple times?